# onClick only works on everyother li

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

So I am trying to make a list of items and when I click on them it toggles a class "done". I am trying to not use jQuery.

Here is what I come up with so far:

Currently, my issue is I am able to add items to the list as a `li` but only every other item will have a class of "done" added to it on click.

Can someone shed some light on why this would be? Been confused.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Javascript + DOM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping list</h1>
    <br> 
   <input id="userInput" placeholder="enter item" type="text">
   <button id="button">enter</button>
   <br>

    <ul class="list">
    </ul>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
    var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

// strikethrough task on click
function strike() {
    for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) 
    {
        li[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
            if(this.classList.contains("iteJm")) {
                this.classList.toggle("done");
            }
        }); 
    }
}

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.classList.add('item');
    input.value = '';
    strike();
}

function addToListAfterClick() {
    if(inputLength() > 0) {
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addToListAfterEnter(event) {
    if(inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode == 13) {
        createListElement();

     }
}

button.addEventListener('click',addToListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener('keypress', addToListAfterEnter);
```

**Here is the CSS:**

```
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the typo, you've in `this.classList.contains("iteJm")` note the extra `J`, you're attaching multiple click event to the items, so every time new `li` added a new event will be attached to all the `li`'s what makes the click event work unproperly, I suggest for you to attach the click when you create the `li` :

```
li.addEventListener('click', strike);
```

If the event attached two times the toggle function will add and remove the class and you'll not see any change, if three it will be added, removed then added and you will see the class there and so on when you add the forth `li` the first one will have 4 click events and you'll notice no change when you click...

```js
var input = document.getElementById('userInput');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

// strikethrough task on click
function strike() {
  if (this.classList.contains("item")) {
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  }
}

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.classList.add('item');
  input.value = '';
  li.addEventListener('click', strike);
}

function addToListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

function addToListAfterEnter(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode == 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', addToListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener('keypress', addToListAfterEnter);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Shopping list</h1>
<br>
<input id="userInput" placeholder="enter item" type="text">
<button id="button">enter</button>
<br>

<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input , I can see where I went wrong.